# Align text baseline with a button in CSS

Tags: css, alignment

I would like to achieve one of the two alignments represented on this image: [image: problem representation]. CSS3 is ok or even better if it makes things simpler.

My main problem is that I managed to align one div containing the text with the button, but the text itself is aligned with the top of the div and not the bottom.

Comment: you can always achieve it by ussing padding-top, but you probably know this

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think what you're after is `vertical-align: text-bottom;`

http://jsfiddle.net/EQgFF/3/

```css
p.box {
    color:#fff;
    background:#444;
    width:400px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

span { background: #666; }

input { vertical-align: text-bottom; border: 1px solid #CCC; height: 24px; }
```

```html
<p class="box"><span>some text</span> <input type="button" value="Button"/></p>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this only solves the first case (align the block elements). @Roko's answer solves the second.

Comment: The key for me was learning that you have to use "vertical-align" on the /button/, not on the block of text, in combination with line-height on the text.

Answer (score 41):

You can use: `line-height`!

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  height:      40px;  
  line-height: 40px; /* Same as height  */
}
```

```html
<p class="box">some text <input type="button" value="Button" /></p>
```

set for the button parent,
where, as you can see, `line-height` matches the element `height`
and will align both texts at the element's (`p`) center.
Otherwise, the button, being an `inline` element by default, it's subject to manipulations using the CSS property `vertical-align:` which basically aligns all *inline** elements vertically inside a **block** level element using this typography terms:

```
vertical-align: baseline;
vertical-align: sub;
vertical-align: super;
vertical-align: text-top;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
vertical-align: middle;
vertical-align: top;
vertical-align: bottom;
vertical-align: 10em;  
vertical-align: 4px;
vertical-align: 20%;
```

*<sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align</sub>

exactly, you can even manually adjust the alignment using `PX` / `-PX` and `%`

I've encountered some issues using line-height on Android browsers (), so sometimes the right solution was to play with the parent **padding** * and vertical-align rather than the inner children's alignments (with line-height).

*<sub>(note: **padding** for block elements is more consistent than (top, bottom) used on inner inline elements.)</sub>

Comment: Seems almost perfect: is it possible to set line-height to not a fixed value but instead the height of the div, whatever it has been set to by the layout engine?

Comment: I had always tried to set the line-height of an input separately, but that isn't necessary I see (: thanks for the tip

Comment: @Paul... from your question is not perfectly clear: are your elements inside a Paragraph? a DIV? is the dashed line the TOP of your main DIV or the Bottom line.

Comment: @roXon, sorry, the dashed line was only here to materialize the alignment I would like to achieve. My text and my button are both inside of a div, at the bottom. The text is in the bottom left hand corner, the button is in the bottom right hand corner. Right now, the text is to "high" with respect to the button. The solution you proposed was perfect but it sets the height to 40px so it won't be very robust to fon resizing by the user I guess.