# How do vertically align a Bulma Button in a line of text?

Tags: bulma

So I'm using Bulma via the CDN, have an `<h2>` tag with a `<button>` tag within it:

`<h2 class="title is-size-2-mobile is-3 has-text-white">Step 1: Pick which Cards and/or Cheatsheets youwant to learn from the <button class="button mt-10 has-background-success has-text-info has-text-centered is-vcentered ml-10 mr-10">Cheatsheets</button> in the menu.</h2>`

But this is what it renders as:
[image]

What classes on the button do I need so it aligns vertically with the text?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but since this is the first result that popped up for me, the classes you're looking for involve the `level` layout classes. [This the link to the documentation with examples.](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/level/) Fundamentally, though, you'd wrap your content in a `level` container, and then use `level-item` to align them vertically across the container. You can use other classes to size the content.  This is one way to solve your problem. There are others, of course:

```
<div class="level">
<h2 class="title is-size-2-mobile is-3 has-text-white level-item">
Step 1: Pick which Cards and/or Cheatsheets you want to learn from the 
<button class="button mt-10 has-background-success has-text-info has-text-centered is-vcentered mx-1 level-item">Cheatsheets</button> 
in the menu.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. If you do not want to stretch the whole line, add style="display: inline-flex;" to the div.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the answer I think](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299393/12032180)

Also you can search about `baseline` property in `css`